# Generate two static apps at once with nuxt.js

Tags: nuxt.js

I use nuxt with target static and built with nuxt generate.

I would like to be able to have for example two folders:

- `/pages/app`
- `/pages/main`

When running `nuxt generate` I would like to generate two different dist folders:

- `dist_app`
- `dist_main`

So that I can deploy them in different domains while having all my files in one place, sharing components and so on.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

This is not doable out of the box, meanwhile you can totally use a quick CI command to `cd` and `mv` the directory (either `app` or `main`) to a dedicated folder.
This is mainly some `bash` coding, will be error-proof and quick to edit in case of some future changes.

If you're using Github, [Github actions](https://github.com/features/actions) is a great start!